# Auto assign roles

Tags: 7

I want to auto assign a "default" role for everyone that registers for the site. Is there any way to do this by default in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this using Rules... just add the action "After saving a new user account" with the action "add user role." Rules gives you even more power if you want, to only add that role on certain conditions and more.

Also - I should mention - Drupal does auto-assign the "authenticated user" role to everyone who registers for the site - you can just make sure that the authenticated role has the permissions you want...